# pl sql regular expression get specific occurrence

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string like this: `aa;bb;cc`

Number of chars of each block could be different.

`;` is the delimiter.

I need to take values seperately. For example: I want to take only the occurrence in the second position (bb).

**I tried this:**

```
SELECT trim(regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
   FROM dual 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

**But if I do:**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT trim(regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
   FROM dual 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
  WHERE ROWNUM = 2;
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply write this?

```
 select trim(regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, 2)) str from dual
```

If you want use recursive query use `rownum` with alias in inner query or use `level` pseudocolumn:

```
select str 
  from (
    select level lvl, trim(regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, 2)) str 
      from dual 
      connect by regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null)
  where lvl = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'aa;bb;cc' from dual
), t2 as
(
select trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level)) str,
       level as lvl
   from t 
 connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null
) 
select str 
  from t2
 where lvl = 2;

STR
---
bb
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/ZRQ60617)</kbd>

*I don't suggest you use `rownum` as much as possible, especially queries with subqueries and order by clauses. In your case, `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` returns a value ( and the result is untrustable, I mean may be other than you want for real values derived from tables) but for the other equalities `ROWNUM = 2` or `ROWNUM = 3` even do not return a value.*

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE ROWNUM = 2` will never return any result, as the rownum is calculated from the resultset of the query. But as there never is a first row, ROWNUM =2 will never be reached.

Easiest is to use OFFSET and LIMIT instead:

`SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT trim(regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str 
    FROM dual 
 CONNECT BY  regexp_substr('aa;bb;cc', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`